Error While preforming this login in Raptor
iam performing this logic in raptor and this is he flow chart, i want to convert the X2 into a negitive number but upron assigning "-" infront it is throwing error,
the inputs i gave are A = 2 and B = -8

I have searched for what might be the cause but can't find any, can anyone help me in this

I also don't understand this, but (-1)*X1 works.
